# Is Atomic swapping between ETH and ETC possible?

Tags: contract-design, ether, exchanges, ethereum-classic

Wondering if cross chain atomic swapping between ETH and ETC without using poloniex, then the world can be merged in more cool way.

Answer (score 2):

Yes absolutely. Atomic swapping can be done between any chain with sufficient scripting capabilities. The trouble with atomic swaps is where to maintain the order book.

Comment: Do you have tutorial how do it beetwen ether testnet and others test net?

Comment: Could you explain this a bit more? Maybe your sources?

Comment: if we need to maintain the order book somewhere and somehow, arent we back to a centralised solution?

Comment: Partially - the availability of the order book may be centralized but custody of the funds is not. You wouldn't have to transfer funds to an exchange, just commit to what orders you want to place (of course, they'd need someway to guarantee you have the funds, so it's a bit non trivial). But at least they wouldn't be able to run away with your coins.